# How dynamically include css basing on logged_in/logged_out status in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using template layout that contains front page set and admin panel set (each sets contains its own CSS).

I want to use front page CSS only if user is **not** logged in, and admin panel set only if user **is** logged in. How can I achieve this in rails, without link hrefs? Currently all CSS are loaded and mixed together from assets folder at once.

Comment: what do you mean "*without link hrefs*"? it sounds like a simple `if...else` statement

Comment: It means I'd like to use assets pipeline default rails behaviour, instead of, for example, if/else with 30 hrefs to css scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a method that chooses the layout for a particular controller:

```
layout :choose_layout

def choose_layout
   current_user.present? ? "this_layout" : "other_layout"
end
```

Comment: "this_layout" and "other_layout" are CSS files?

Comment: a layout has it's own markup and css. Go to the layouts directory of your app and add a new layout that has it's own custom markup and css classes.

Comment: yes. if you wanted to use the application layout it would be `"application"`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you should:

- have two separate layouts but keep a dir with shared partials (use as many partials as possible)
- separate CSS files (eg use guest.css and admin.css) but also keep another "shared.css" file where you keep things like .no-paddings .no-margins .hidden .pull-left and so on... so you don't duplicate any code
- separate javascript in the same manner

You never know why/when you'll decide to merge the two layouts but keep the CSS separate, or the other way around - apps change in time, so DRY.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions, luckily I've done it as You've said :)